# Bootstrap modal style in Kendo popup window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I use Kendo window and want to style it as Boststrap modals as on [this](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) page.
Is it possible to do this by using a template property or etc. of Kendo window? Here is the Kendo Window definition below:

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("CreateWindow")
    .Title("Create New")
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Content("Loading...")
    .LoadContentFrom("_Create", "Issue")
    .Width(800)
    .Height(600)
    .Modal(true)    
    .Draggable()
    .Actions(actions => actions.Close()) 
)
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own style by overriding the css. I don't think the media queries are defined for kendo window, so you will also need to need to define them as well to support responsiveness. Or you can use kendo ui bootstrap theme that can get you closest to the bootstrap theme.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you mentioned, I used kendo-bootstrap css, but I need a good header and footer style (at least there are some nice footers for modal popup in bootstrap). Any idea or sample?

Comment: You can easily see the CSS style being used using developer tools and then override them based on your site theme. For me I liked more of zurb look and completed did away with the header and footer.

Comment: Do you mean to copy and apply the CSS style from the sample page to my page by changing the conflicted properties with **override**? If not, what do you mean with